# NodeJS Error: Cannot GET/ from running the url on the web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

This type of question has been asked a few times here in Stackoverflow but none fixed my issue.

That's why I'm popping out my questions here. While running http://localhost:3000/messages on the browser, I get an error

> **Cannot GET /messages**

from the following code. Any help would be of great kind !!

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.get("/messages", (req, res) => {
    res.render("Hello");
   });

var server = app.listen(3000, () =>{
    console.log('server is listening on port', server.address().port)
})
```

Comment: use `res.send("Hello");` instead of `render`

Answer (score 1):

Try res.json instead of render.

```
app.get("/messages", (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'messages view'});
   });
 app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'Welcome home'});
   });
```

Package.json file should be

```
{
  "name": "sample project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Because you are not using any view engine that is why its not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

modify your code to be like this :

```
app.get('/messages', (req, res) => { res.json({msg: 'messages view'}); }); app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.json({message: 'Stay at home'}); });
```

because you didn't use any engine for the frontend to ***render*** like *ejs* or *pug*.